# How to filter a variable inside a function in R?

Tags: r, function, filtering

I need help with something really simple in R. I defined a function to perform few operations and I'm unable to select the variable while calling the function using input parameters.

Eg: Using mpg dataset just for reference, I need to filter out all columns where disp > 2.0

```
mpg 

#Defining a simple function called select_fun

select_fun <- function(x)
  {

  a <- mpg %>% filter(x >  2) 

  return(a)

}

select_fun("disp")

Output: 

<chr> model disp  year  cyl  trans     drv  cty  hwy   class
audi    a4  1.8 1999    4   auto(l5)    f   18  29  p   compact
audi    a4  1.8 1999    4   manual(m5)  f   21  29  p   compact
audi    a4  2.0 2008    4   manual(m6)  f   20  31  p   compact
audi    a4  2.0 2008    4   auto(av)    f   21  30  p   compact
audi    a4  2.8 1999    6   auto(l5)    f   16  26  p   compact
audi    a4  2.8 1999    6   manual(m5)  f   18  26  p   compact
audi    a4  3.1 2008    6   auto(av)    f   18  27  p   compact
```

The output is incorrect as the filtered values are still present. 
Maybe I'm missing out on something really simple and dumb!!
Any help would be really appreciated
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways in which you can solve this problem :

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
```

1) Use `filter_at` :

```
select_fun1 <- function(df, x) {
   a <- df %>% filter_at(vars(x), any_vars(. > 2))
   return(a)
}
```

2) Use base R subsetting

```
select_fun2 <- function(df, x) {
   a <- df[df[[x]] > 2,]
   return(a)
}
```

3) Use non-standard evaluation

```
select_fun3 <- function(df, x) {
   a <- df %>% filter(!!sym(x) > 2)
   return(a)
}
```

Check the results from 3 are the same.

```
identical(select_fun1(mpg, 'displ'), select_fun2(mpg, 'displ'))
#[1] TRUE
identical(select_fun1(mpg, 'displ'), select_fun3(mpg, 'displ'))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Might have clicked it accidentally. Your answer was precise!! Thanks, now I can filter out all z-score range for all variables using a similar function.

Answer (score 0):

One more, almost identical to Ronak Shah's `select_fun3` but a bit shorter (thanks to `curly-curly` operator) and not you don't need to quote variable name with it:

```
select_fun4 <- function(df, x) {
   df %>% filter({{x}} > 2)
   }

select_fun4(mpg, displ)
# A tibble: 191 x 11
   manufacturer model      displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class  
   <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  
 1 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compact
 2 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compact
 3 audi         a4           3.1  2008     6 auto(av)   f        18    27 p     compact
 4 audi         a4 quattro   2.8  1999     6 auto(l5)   4        15    25 p     compact
 5 audi         a4 quattro   2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) 4        17    25 p     compact
 6 audi         a4 quattro   3.1  2008     6 auto(s6)   4        17    25 p     compact
 7 audi         a4 quattro   3.1  2008     6 manual(m6) 4        15    25 p     compact
 8 audi         a6 quattro   2.8  1999     6 auto(l5)   4        15    24 p     midsize
 9 audi         a6 quattro   3.1  2008     6 auto(s6)   4        17    25 p     midsize
10 audi         a6 quattro   4.2  2008     8 auto(s6)   4        16    23 p     midsize
# ... with 181 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it